# Create an api with spring-boot and twitter social login for post tweet with image

Tags: spring-boot, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm asking myself if it's possible to build a rest api with spring-boot and twitter social login(oauth), and then, allow users to tweet with an image.

A the very begining i just wanted to tweet with an image from the client (rest call via javascript), but i figured out that was not possible unless with twitter card.

thanks you very much for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to apply to get a developer account. After this, you will be able to register your application to obtain all required secrets/tokens that will be used by your application in all twitter API calls. See [detailed steps for oauth login here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/3-legged-oauth).

Uploading a picture in Twitter is a 2 steps process:

1. Upload the picture using the endpoint: `POST media/upload`. See [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload)

   1.1. Extract the media_id from the response for using it in the next step
2. Create a tweet referecing this image with the endpoint: `POST statuses/update`. See [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update#post-statuses-update)

Finally, `Twitter4J` is an unofficial client that can ease that for you. See the following example for uploading images: [https://github.com/Twitter4J/Twitter4J/blob/master/twitter4j-examples](https://github.com/Twitter4J/Twitter4J/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/tweets/UploadMultipleImages.java)

Comment: thanks you for information, but do you think it's possible to tweet with Twitter4J with other account than the account which is use to get the consumer and secret key ? as i know , it's not possible. in other word , i want to sign in twitter with basic auth, and then after that, update tweet. i'm afraid it's not possible...

Comment: Yes, it is. The developer account will get you the possibility to use OAuth with any Twitter Account. Then when a user of your application will log into your application and he will be asked to grant your application some capabilities: such as reading its user information (name, mail), posting tweets for him, ...